# Unknown custom element: <HamburgerMenu> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to fire an event from my parent HamburgerCross to my child HamburgerMenu. But when I try to register my component with the name hamburgerMenu it starts throwing errors. It says that the element HamburgerMenu is unknown. How can I solve this problem?

```
<template>
      <div>
            <div class="grid-item-4">
                <HamburgerCross @onToggle="toggleHamburgerMenu" />
                <HamburgerMenu :links="links" ref="hamburgerMenu" />
            </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>

    import ButtonItem from '@/components/widgets/clickables/button_item.vue'
    import LanguageSelect from '@/components/widgets/language_select.vue'
    import HamburgerCross from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu_cross.vue'
    import HamburgerMenu from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu.vue'
    export default {
        components:{
            ButtonItem,
            LanguageSelect,
            HamburgerCross,
            'hamburgerMenu' : HamburgerMenu,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                title: 'BLOCKBURN',
                links: {'About' : '/about', 'Dapp' : '/dapp', 'Game' : '/game', 'Roadmap' : '/roadmap'},
                defaultLanguage: 'uk',
                buttonText: 'BUY BURN IEO',
                buttonTheme: 'secondary',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            toggleHamburgerMenu(){
                console.log('toggle nav');
                this.$refs.hamburgerMenu.toggle();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter but why are you registering it using `'hamburgerMenu' : HamburgerMenu` rather than just `HamburgerMenu`, like the others? To debug further I suggest adding a `created` hook with the logging `console.log(this.$options.components)`. That may shed some light on what is going wrong.

Comment: Becuase I want to use it with my ref

Comment: Registering it in the `components` section with a lower-case first letter won't have any impact on the `ref`.

Comment: Actually, I said it shouldn't matter but I was wrong. That is the cause of the problem. Get rid of the `'hamburgerMenu' : ` part and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
      <div>
            <div class="grid-item-4">
                <HamburgerCross @onToggle="toggleHamburgerMenu" />
                <HamburgerMenu :links="links" ref="hamburgerMenu" />
            </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>

    import ButtonItem from '@/components/widgets/clickables/button_item.vue'
    import LanguageSelect from '@/components/widgets/language_select.vue'
    import HamburgerCross from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu_cross.vue'
    import HamburgerMenu from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu.vue'
    export default {
        components:{
            ButtonItem,
            LanguageSelect,
            HamburgerCross,
            HamburgerMenu,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                title: 'BLOCKBURN',
                links: {'About' : '/about', 'Dapp' : '/dapp', 'Game' : '/game', 'Roadmap' : '/roadmap'},
                defaultLanguage: 'uk',
                buttonText: 'BUY BURN IEO',
                buttonTheme: 'secondary',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            toggleHamburgerMenu(){
                console.log('toggle nav');
                this.$refs.hamburgerMenu.toggle();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

remove `'hamburgerMenu'` and it'll be fine. like you mention in comment that you want to use it with ref, there's no impact on `ref` like skirtle said if you're registering it on component.

Comment: I don't get it why does toggleHamburgerMenu not get triggered I throw the even in the parent with this.$emit("onToggle", this.open);

Comment: is it display `toggle nav` in the console?